# Are Gaussian Process Upper Confidence Bound results valid with only exploration based acquisition?

Tags: machine-learning, upper-lower-bounds

I have gone through the GP-UCB [N. Srinivas et.al](https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.3995) where the acquisition function attempts to strike balance between exploration and exploitation. The regression model is $y=f(x)+\varepsilon$  following all the conditions mentioned in the original manuscript. The Gaussian process is given as $y(x) \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu(x),\sigma^2(x))$. The GP-UCB acquisition function is:

$$x_{t+1}=\arg max_x=\mu_t(x)+\sqrt{\beta_{t+1}}\sigma_t(x)$$

This leads to the result where the probability of the difference between mean estimate $\mu(x)$ and true (but unknown) function $f(x)$ is bounded as, with $\delta \in  (0,1)$
$$\mathbb{P}\bigg \{|f(x)-\mu_T(x)|\leq \sqrt{\beta_{t+1}}\sigma_t(x) \bigg \} \geq 1-\delta $$

My question is that if i modify the acquisition function to perform pure exploration as
$x_{t+1}=\arg max_x=\sqrt{\beta_{t+1}}\sigma_t(x)$, does the result on probabilisitc bound hold? Or I need to modify the bound as well.

My understanding is that if the function is sampled from a Gaussian process, then the bound should hold irrespective of the acquation function. Something similar to the Hoeffding’s Inequality based UCB in [Given in this blog](https://lilianweng.github.io/lil-log/2018/01/23/the-multi-armed-bandit-problem-and-its-solutions.html). How can I construct argument to show that, if true.